# How does a bigdecimal's precision change upon converting to string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.8.7

I stumbled upon a very weird behaviour. A normal bigdecimal value when converted to string using **to_s** method changes it's behaviour.

There is a normal **float** column in my table and a record has the value **37502**

When I fetch the record and print it in view using

```
"some text "+ my_record.amount.to_s
```

I get the output as

```
37502.0390625
```

I am perplexed with this behaviour

Comment: You have a float value and convert it to a string. How exactly is that related to BigDecimal?

Comment: I tried amount.class and for which it returned BigDecimal